# Implementing twitter posts synchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, twitter

Hi I am using this code [here](http://punyweakling.com/add-a-tweet-bbcode-for-a-phpbb-forum/) to embed twitter posts in my website. It works fine on the pages where the code is used (in the forums, for example), however, when browsing through the user profiles page, the post history of each user is generated using ajax because there are other sections for all user activities on the website and the problems start here. In the console I get the following error message:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

This is causing the twitter posts to not be displayed.

Any ideas how I could embed twitter posts *synchronously*? I looked through the twitter documentation, but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Youve found the wrong solution. Never ever do stuff synchronously. And never ever use document.write. You can simply append to bodys inner Content (even after the page loaded and the twitter request finished):

```
document.body.innerHTML += "some twitter stuff";
```

Comment: I tried replacing it but it's not going to work. It is appending the tweet to the page but not where I want it to be. What other alternative is there? I tried with `document.getElementByClassName('twitter').innerHTML` but nothing is happening.

Comment: Use a [0] to select just tue first element that has class twitter document.getElementsByClassName("twitter")[0].innerHTML +="sth"

Comment: This made no difference.